# ByteArrayInputStream#read() strange behaviour for negative input bytes

Tags: java, io, byte, arrays, inputstream

I faced with this code in test.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { -1, 1, 0x0 }; 
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); 
System.out.println(in.read() + in.read() + in.read());
```

I expected that this code returns 0 (-1+1+0) but it returns 256.

I am very wondered.

Who can explain this bahaviour?

**P.S.**

Revealed that the first statement returns 255. Why?

Comment: this is because `read()` method, reads the data(each 1 byte) as integer(4 bytes)

Comment: @parsa porahmad  can you show it in details?

Comment: According to [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) the `read()` method reads the next byte and returns it as integer. it means it adds 3 bytes empty(nul) byte at left actual value and returns it, so the -1 will be 255, not clear yet?

Comment: But it is not expected(for me) behaviour for negative values of byte

Comment: you can use `DataInputStream` instead of `InputStream` class, it has a method `readByte()` which reads a byte and returns it as byte too.

Comment: The other way to interpret the read() is that it will return an "unsigned" byte as an int.

Comment: @anonymous are there exist this realization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and you will see why.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class Test006 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { -1, 1, 0x0 }; 
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        System.out.println(in.read());
        System.out.println(in.read());
        System.out.println(in.read());
    }

}
```

The first number is read as the int 255 and so the sum is 256.

The value -1 looks like this as a byte.
1111 1111

Apparently, when it's read as an int, Java does not add leading 1s
(to preserve the sign which would turn it into the int -1) but adds
leading zeroes. So this int becomes:

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111

And this is the int 255 not -1.

The int -1 looks like this:

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

So... This is where the int 255 comes from.

Comment: **first number is read as the int 255** it is point of question

Comment: why as int ? constructor looks like **public ByteArrayInputStream(byte buf[])...**

Comment: Yes, but the method `read` returns int not byte. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29

Comment: Hence sign bit represents as value bit?

Comment: Yes, the byte value -n (for each n in the interval [1, 128]) is read back as the int value 256-n. This is the general pattern here. Try it with e.g. -1, -2, -5, -100, -127, -128.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`InputStream#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29):

> The value byte is returned as an int in the **range 0 to 255**

Try to print the following and you'll understand:

```
System.out.println(in.read());  //prints 255
System.out.println(in.read());  //prints 1
System.out.println(in.read());  //prints 0
```

So 256 is actually 255 + 1 + 0.

EDIT:

`read()` method reads one byte at a time. In Java, a *byte* is represented in 8-bit in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), if your `int` is in range [128, 255] the cast to `byte` will be [-1, -128] respectively.

Comment: I don't understand why first statement returns 255

Comment: Because -1 = 0xFF and widen to int 0xFFFFFFFF. Then take the first byte only 0xFFFFFFFF & 0xFF = 0x000000FF. That's how you get 255 as an int.

Comment: int 128 cast to byte = -128. int 255 cast to byte = -1